# Not able to link products to related opportunities using nested map

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have a requirement to display Opportunities and related products based on product fammily.

Ex:

```
Opportunity 1
   Product Family 1
      Product 1
      Product 2
   Product Family 2
      Product 3
      Product 4
```

I have tried to achieve the requirement using nested map. But I was not getting expected result.
Here is the code that I developed.

```
public class OppsAndProductsController {
    @auraEnabled
    public static Map<String,Map<String,List<OpportunityLineItem>>> fetchOppsAndProducts() {
        Map<String,Map<String,List<OpportunityLineItem>>> oppProductsMap = new Map<String,Map<String,List<OpportunityLineItem>>>();
        Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
        List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity];
        for(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
            oppIds.add(opp.Id);
        }
        Map<String,List<OpportunityLineItem>> productMap = new Map<String,List<OpportunityLineItem>>();
        for(OpportunityLineItem oppLine : [SELECT Product2.Name, Product2.Family, Opportunity.Name
                                           FROM OpportunityLineItem 
                                           WHERE OpportunityId IN: oppIds 
                                           AND Product2.Family != NULL 
                                           AND OpportunityId != NULL]) {
                                               if(productMap.containsKey(oppLine.Product2.Family)) {
                                                   productMap.get(oppLine.Product2.Family).add(oppLine);
                                               }
                                               else {
                                                   productMap.put(oppLine.Product2.Family, new List<OpportunityLineItem> {oppLine});
                                               }
                                               oppProductsMap.put(oppLine.Opportunity.Name,productMap);
                                           }
        return oppProductsMap;
    }
}
```

Can someone help me what I am missing in this code to get my result. Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `productMap` has been declared outside the for-loop, the same instance of that map will be put in relation with every Opportunity Name, while you need to create a new instance of that map for each Opporunity, so its declaration must be inside the for-loop.
Of course you need to create a new instance only if you don't find it in the outer map, the one you're going to return.

```
public with sharing class OppsAndProductsController {
    @auraEnabled
    public static Map<String, Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>> fetchOppsAndProducts() {
        Map<String, Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>> mapOpporunityNameMapProductFamilyProductList = new Map<String, Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>>();

        for(OpportunityLineItem oppLine : [SELECT Product2.Name, Product2.Family, Opportunity.Name
                                           FROM OpportunityLineItem
                                           WHERE Product2.Family != NULL]) { // Be sure to add more conditions in order to filter this query

            Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>> mapProductFamilyProductList = mapOpporunityNameMapProductFamilyProductList.get(oppLine.Opportunity.Name);
            if (mapProductFamilyProduct == null) { // If it is the first time we meet this Opportunity.Name...
                mapProductFamilyProduct = new Map<String, List<OpportunityLineItem>>(); // ...create a new instance...
                mapOpporunityNameMapProductFamilyProductList.put(oppLine.Opportunity.Name, mapProductFamilyProduct); // ...and add it to the map, so the next time will be retrieved
            } // After this line mapProductFamilyProductList will never be null and will always be related to a specific Opportunity

            List<OpportunityLineItem> productList = mapProductFamilyProductList.get(oppLine.Product2.Family);
            if (productList == null) { // Same as above
                productList = new List<OpportunityLineItem>();
                mapProductFamilyProductList.put(oppLine.Product2.Family, productList);
            } // After this line productList will never be null and will always be related to a specific Product Family related to a specific Opportunity
            productList.add(oppLine);
        }

        return mapOpporunityNameMapProductFamilyProductList;
    }
}
```

If you only need a list of Product Name, you should change the signature to `public static Map<String, Map<String, List<String>>> fetchOppsAndProducts()`, then modify the code accordingly.

---

I removed the following block of code because it is useless:

```
Set<Id> oppIds = new Set<Id>();
List<Opportunity> oppList = [SELECT Id, Name FROM Opportunity];
for(Opportunity opp : oppList) {
    oppIds.add(opp.Id);
}
```

There are no WHERE condition, so you're going to retrive every Opportunity in the org, then `OpportunityId IN: oppIds` simply means "get everything", so no Opportunity Line Item will be filtered out.

**Beware**: you really should filter that query somehow, because even if the class would be `with sharing`, a single user could see more than 50000 OpportunityLineItem in a real scenario.

Comment: Thanks for your help. It helped me solve multiple similar issues...